# Should you create a reference the main class in every class in Java?

Tags: java, performance

I have a big program and I use my main class in almost every class. I usually access by a getInstance method but I do that every time I need it. For example:

```
OITCPlugin.getInstance().get....
```

Now I wonder if that is very efficient and if it was better if I declare a variable for it and access the variable instead:

```
private OITCPlugin plugin = OITCPlugin.getInstance();
...
plugin.get...
```

And if I only need it in one method is it more efficient and ram saving if I only declare it in the method itself?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doing this usually means that there is a design problem somewhere. I suggest you read about design patterns first. Maybe that will allow you to better structure your code and avoid such instances. Having all the objects as singletons is not good.
Also, maybe read about dependency injection

Comment: @PetrePopescu already said the most important, you have a design problem. That being said you can, in every class you need access main, declare something like that just once, private obj = OITCPlugin.getInstance().getMyCustomObj(); then just use obj where you need it

Comment: If you're planning to use the Singleton pattern, use an Enum instead. Check [this blog](https://dev.to/abh1navv/ways-to-create-singletons-and-the-tradeoffs-between-them-ofd) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#:%7E:text=In%20software%20engineering%2C%20the%20singleton,mathematical%20concept%20of%20a%20singleton.) is a common approach if you only want one instance of the object. A lot of people regard it as an anti-pattern, yet it is still very popular. [Spring beans are singletons](https://blog.marcnuri.com/spring-bean-scopes-guide-to-understand-the-different-bean-scopes#:%7E:text=web%2Daware%20application.-,Singleton,same%20object%20will%20be%20injected.), and [redux store](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#:%7E:text=If%20you%20create%20a%20store,store%20instances%20for%20every%20request.) is a singleton!

If you are only using it in one method, you might as well free up the heap and store it locally in the method, as described [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-are-java-objects-stored-in-memory). Freeing up the heap will technically give better performance, but Java is not exactly a super-efficient language anyway, and it also manages the memory for you. Memory generally isn't a problem though, because it's quite cheap and we have lots of it (maybe I should be more careful about my memory management!)

Comment: Thanks, the only reason why I care about the performance is that I want to make my programs as efficient as possible. I actually code Minecraft Plugins and since I have lots of servers my code runs extremly often and every optimization is making a difference

Comment: That sounds awesome, touche :D